# how to find duplicate item position from set in java

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public class Practise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        int[] array = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
                    set.add(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(set);

    }
}
```

this is my code i am able to find duplicate element 1 and 8 but i want its position also in set which position these item is there please suggest me how to implement it .  i have to get all duplicate item second postion i mean int[] array = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 }; it should show 1 is in first postion and 8 is in 9 th postion

Comment: Isn't `i` the index so also the position?

Comment: A set cannot contain duplicate items and it doesn't have any ordering, so you cannot find the *position* of a *duplicate item* in a set. For an array it's easy - you insert all elements in a set but before inserting you check if it already exists in the set. If so, it's duplicate.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? A set cannot contain duplicates so by adding every element in `array` to `set`, `set` would only contain unique entries and `set.add()` would return false when trying to insert an element already contained in the set.

Comment: yes i want its position also

Comment: so u mean we should put it in array actully i have to get all duplicate item second postion i mean  int[] array = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 };  it should show 1 is in first postion and 8  is in 9 th postion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Practise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int[] array = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 };
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
                    result.put(i, array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to know the position of the duplicate it's quite easy. As @Kagemusha already mentioned the method `add` of `Set` returns `true` if the element was added and `false` if the element is already present in the set. So the only thing you would need to do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     if(!set.add(array[i]) {
       //i is now the position of the duplicate
       duplicate_position = i;
    }
}
```

Edit: I see that @LiuJie also added a correct answer. I still want to make a case for my solution. In your case with such a small array there is not much difference but the complexity of his answer is O(n^2) (we really want to avoid this kind of complexities) where my solution is only O(n) (it does require additional space but only if you're not going to use the set).

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> rs=new HashMap<>();  
        int[] array = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                if(array[i]==array[j] && i!=j){

                    rs.put(array[i], i);
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple logic which prints all the repeated numbers along with their positions

```
int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 7, 8};

for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            System.out.println("Number: "+arr[i]+" found repeating at position: "+i+" , repeated at position "+j);
        }
    }
}
```